# Convert CBUUID to NSNumber in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, swift5, uint16

How Can I convert a CBUUID to UINT16?

I want to procure the device information in the advertisement data as UINT16.

I am getting the error

**Could not cast value of type 'CBUUID' (0x1d2715e68) to 'NSNumber' (0x1d25c9db0).
2019-12-04 14:17:18.731697-0500 ProjectName[717:125723] Could not cast value of type 'CBUUID' (0x1d2715e68) to 'NSNumber' (0x1d25c9db0).**

**My Advertisement Data in terminal**

[
"kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel": 0,
"kCBAdvDataIsConnectable": 1, 
"kCBAdvDataTimestamp": 597179838.727399,
 "kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs": <__NSArrayM 0x281252e20>(
22043200-9530-4EA8-9D21-04146852E51F
)
,
 "kCBAdvDataServiceData": {
    "Device Information" = {length = 6, **bytes = 0x010000020004**};
}, 
"kCBAdvDataLocalName": base0
]

I have highlighted the information which I need in Bold.

**I have the following code below.**

```
    public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        guard peripheral.state != .connected else {
            return
        }


        let advertisementDataService = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey]
        let deviceInformation = advertisementDataService as! Dictionary<UInt16,AnyObject>
}
```

Thank You!!!

Comment: You can't. A CBUUID is a 128 bit identifier. A UInt16 is a 16 bit number.   What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to access the byte information  from "kCBAdvDataServiceData": { "Device Information" = {length = 6, bytes = 0x010000020004}; }, and assign this to a variable and publish it to my project because this is a package and then store it in Database. So whenever I scan any peripheral the peripheral should match my the value from database and then connect after scanning.This is part of my requirement. If you have a better solution to achieve this please let me know.

Comment: You need to specify your dictionary as `<CBUUID, Data>`  as per the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdataservicedatakey

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 but I have an error.... Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an argument of type 'CBUUID'... I cannot subscript the information.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation[(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdataservicedatakey), the dictionary associated with `CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey` is of type `<CBUUID,Data>`.  Having retrieved the dictionary you can then subscript it using the appropriate `CBUUID` instance (0x180A is the Device Information service).

```
public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    guard peripheral.state != .connected else {
        return
    }


    if let deviceInformation = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey] as? Dictionary<CBUUID,Data>, 
       let data = deviceInformation[CBUUID(string:"0x180A")] {
        // Do something with the data
    }
}
```